# linear span of set of independent vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

for basis of vector , we need to prove that a set of vectors is contained in that space and should be linearly independent .But how to show that linear span of that set of linearly independent vectors span a vector space ?

Comment: If you can show any arbitrary vector can be expanded in terms of the basis vectors.

Comment: i do not get it

Comment: If you have any vector for e.g. in 3D it can be written in terms of x, y, z(basis vectors). Similarly, show this for any arbitrary dimension.

Comment: This question is too general: please give more details in order to get an answer.